# Change Permission - System cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am a domain admin and am trying to added a user to a folder giving them acces to that folder and all subfolders and files. When I attempt to give them access I get an error message "The system cannot find the file specified." I can see the file in the folder though however when I try to open in I get the message "Cannot find the specified file - Check path or spelling". When I go to Properties and select Security I get "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed."

This happens to almost all but not all files in the folder. Any file showing a modifed date of 2011 or older I get this trouble but any that have a modified date of 2012 or newer work.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Are you accessing these files via a share or are you directly on the server hosting these shares? If accessing via share I'd rdp into the server to see if things behave differently. If they behave the same I'd go to the directory within the cmd prompt and do an xcalc on the files, what happens?

Comment: I was connected as a share before. I logged in using my account, which is a member of the domain admin group, and tried to copy to a different location and received the same "Cannot find…" message. I then cmd icacls path\file and got the message "Access is denied." Taking ownership of all of these files will be a last resort but just before other drastic measures such as running a check disk.

Comment: if you take ownership of one file does that fix it for that file?

Comment: Taking ownership did fix the problem which is what I ended having to do. For those that want to know, I used takeown /F "dir" /R /A.
I just did the whole folder contents since I had a problem with most of the files instead of just a few.